# Is Etherum or Hyperledger be helpful for Money Lending business without Miners reward without using Cryptocurrency?

Tags: ether, hyperledger

If I have to implement something like Money Lending Business on a Private - Enterprise level in India provided the facts that -

1. I don't want to reward the miners as it's a private network.
2. I want to execute smart contracts in INR. currency (Smart contract use case - A is lending some money to B on a agreed interest rate, expects that back after 6 months of span.)

Is Ethereum platform be a help for me? Or else any other options too exist? Any suggestions about how can we do that ?

Answer (score 1):

From what you described, I think you're looking for a private/permissioned blockchain solution, there are a few solutions out there including :

- Hyperledger Fabric by IBM just hit 1.0 in July
- Quorum is an "enterprise-focused version of Ethereum" as described on the JP Morgan website
- Corda by R3

How do you expect the smart contract to enforce the debt collection ? you'd need to keep some kind of collateral in the contract ...

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger is useful for your problem statement as mining is not required in the process, however for ethereum based architecture mining will be required.